# Cannot re-save PDF Generated in PDF Sharp 101 Error

Tags: adobe, pdfsharp, migradoc

I have a PDF I have generated using PDFSharp/MigraDoc.
The PDF opens fine and everything is viewable.

If I try and re-save the PDF under a new name or add password protection to it in adobe it tells me it
"The document could not be saved. There was a problem reading this document (110)"

IS there any way of seeing specifically what the problem is with the way I have generated it, I am not sure where to start debugging!

Comment: Are you using the latest version 6.1.0 Preview 1? You can find PDF file checkers on the web, maybe they can give you a clue.